# Group rows that have values with the condition : value1=value2+1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two columns in an oracle database:

```
SHIFTIME_NO| UserId|
-------+----------
240016     | 24    |
240017     | 24    |
240016     | 24    |
240017     | 24    |
240016     | 24    |
240016     | 24    |
240021     | 24    |
240022     | 24    |
240022     | 24    |
```

My goal is to group each two values that have the condition(value1=value2+1) into one value(min(value1,value2)).
For this example, I would like to have something like this:

```
 SHIFTIME_NO| UserId|
    -------+----------
    240016     | 24    |
    240021     | 24    |
```

Your help with be much appreciated.

Comment: So what is the expected result if your data includes 240018 as well as 240016 and 240017? All 3 combined, or one row with 240016 & 240017 and another row with 240017 & 240018?

Comment: Hello Chris,,my data has always a difference that is equal to 1 or bigger/equal to 3.

Comment: Seems you only need to pick odd numbered rows given distinct shiftime_no. How about the value of userID - can that be different for same shiftime_no, for e.g. can there be different userID for say shiftime_no=16?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, same userID for same shiftime_id, following query can be used -

```
select shiftime_no, userid from 
(
select shiftime_no, UserID, row_number() over 
(order by shiftime_no) rn from tab1 group by shiftime_no, UserID
) where mod(rn,2)<>0
```

fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a8562eea7af2b296f83a03b09911c07).

Answer (score 1):

To simply get the exact outcome you have described, you can just use DISTINCT and JOIN the current entry with the entry having shiftime_no +1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.shiftime_no, y.userid
FROM yourtable y JOIN yourtable y2
ON y2.shiftime_no = y.shiftime_no +1;
```

Since you asked the question in that way, I assume you are sure you really want to get exactly this result. If not, you will to have further conditions or to add some selects with union to add as example the lowest and the highest number of your table. Or to group by userid etc. Please ask the question more precise if you require further assistance.